# What is the meaning of "0,/xxx" in sed?

Tags: bash, sed

A sed command used in a script as following:

```
sed -i "0,/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/s/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/ENABLE_DEBUG = YES/" MakeConfig
```

I knows that

```
s/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/ENABLE_DEBUG = YES/
```

is to substitutes line prefix

`ENABLE_DEBUG` as `ENABLE_DEBUG = YES`

But no idea about the meaning of

```
0,/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) for details of addresses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`0,/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/` means that the substitution will only occur on lines from the beginning, `0`, to the first line that matches `/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/`.  No substitution will be made on subsequent lines even if they match `/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/`

#### Other examples of ranges

This will substitute only on lines 2 through 5:

```
sed '2,5 s/old/new/'
```

This will substitute from line 2 to the first line after it which includes `something`:

```
sed '2,/something/ s/old/new/'
```

This will substitute from the first line that contains `something` to the end of the file:

```
sed '/something/,$ s/old/new/'
```

#### POSIX vs. GNU ranges: the meaning of line "0"

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat test.txt
one
two
one
three
```

Now, let's apply sed over the range `1,/one/`:

```
$ sed '1,/one/ s/one/Hello/' test.txt
Hello
two
Hello
three
```

The range starts with line 1 and ends with the first line *after* line 1 that matches `one`.  Thus two substitutions are made above.

Suppose that we only wanted the first `one` replaced.  With POSIX sed, this cannot be done with ranges.  As  NeronLeVelu points out, GNU sed offers an extension for this case: it allows us to specify the range as `0,/one/`.  This range ends with the first occurrence of `one` in the file:

```
$ sed '0,/one/ s/one/Hello/' test.txt
Hello
two
one
three
```

Thus, the range `0,/^ENABLE_DEBUG/` ends with the first line that begins with `ENABLE_DEBUG` even if that line is the first line.  This requires GNU sed.

Comment: GNU sed only, the address `0` is not recognize by POSIX sed. The GNU evolution allow to have the second address (regex pattern in this case) occuring on first line of file where posix only allow from second line.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Good point.  I added a section to the answer to discuss it.