# SED one liner to uncomment and replace first occurrence of a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have this settings.conf file in linux defined as follows:

```
Section A
  first-setting = value
#  second-setting = off
  third-setting = value

Section B
  first-setting = value
#  second-setting = off
  third-setting = value
```

I would like to uncomment `#  second-setting = off` of Section A only (first occurrence), and set the value to on.

So far, I have this:

`cat settings.conf | sed '/^# second.*/ {s/^#//;s/off/on/}'`

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
sed '0,/#/s/#\(.*\) off/\1 on/' settings.conf
```

Or if your on osx with non-gnu sed:

```
sed '1,/#/s/#\(.*\) off/\1 on/' settings.conf
```

Comment: Also, an [explenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869731/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-xxx-in-sed)

Comment: Yes, this is something like what I was looking for. I had to tweak it a little bit, so that it could search for a more specific pattern, supposing that the file could have comments in the beginning: `sed '0,/#  second.*/s/#\(.*\) off$/\1 on/' settings.conf`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '1,/^Section B/s/#  second-setting = off/  section-setting = on/' settings.conf
```

Comment: While this does work, I was looking for something that is more recyclable... +1 as soon as my reputation goes up!

Comment: I was thinking of `/Section A/,/^$/ s/…/…/`, but I prefer this approach since it looks for the 'second-setting' string rather than random comment lines that might or might not be followed by 'second-setting'.