# Problem inserting on first match only using GNU sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

4 on my linux machine (I checked w/ `sed --version`).

Currently, I have a `myfile.txt` with the following content:

```
---
title: hello
author: Jan King
foo: bar
author: Jan King
---
```

I know in GNU sed, I can append after the first occurrence of a match if I prepend the sed command with `0,`.

So, if I want to insert `goodbye` after the first occurrence of `---`, I can do that:

```sh
 sed -i '0,/---/a goodbye' myfile.txt
```

**expected/correct result:**

```
---
goodbye
title: hello
author: Jan King
foo: bar
author: Jan King
---
```

But now, I am trying to insert `goodbye` after the first occurrence of `author: Jan King`.

However, the following `sed` command doesn't work and appends `goodbye` 3 times, which is not what I want:

```sh
 sed -i '0,/^author:.*/a goodbye' myfile.txt
```

**incorrect/unexpected result:**

```
---
goodbye
title: hello
goodbye
author: Jan King
goodbye
foo: bar
author: Jan King
---
```

If I remove `0,` from the above sed command, then `goodbye` is appended twice after `author: Jan King`:

```sh
 sed -i '/^author:.*/a goodbye' myfile.txt
```

**expected result:**

```sh
---
title: hello
author: Jan King
goodbye
foo: bar
author: Jan King
goodbye
---
```

So I'm having trouble appending `goodbye` on first match only of `author: Jan King` (even though it is fine on first match of `---`).

Can someone please explain why my `sed` command isn't working? And how to fix it?

Comment: *I know in GNU sed, I can append after the first occurrence of a match if I prepend the sed command with `0,`* Can you show where you learned this from? It doesn't evidently behave this way. Try, your first example again but put the first occurrence of the `---` on the third line instead of the first. You'll get similar results as your second example. The `0,/...` you are using will append on *every line* up until the matching line.

Comment: @lurker - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970467/1097123

https://stackoverflow.com/a/148473/1097123

https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html

Comment: See this post: [What is the meaning of “0,/xxx” in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869731/what-is-the-meaning-of-0-xxx-in-sed). It indicates that *`0,/^ENABLE_DEBUG.*/` means that the substitution will only occur **on lines from the beginning***. The link you show is not quite the same command sequence that you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you show in the comment is not quite the same command sequence that you're trying to use. If you want to use the same technique, try:

```
sed -i '0,/^\(author:.*\)/s//\1\nNew Inserted Line/' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the two conditions:

1. the range of lines `0,/^author:/`
2. the specific line inside this range `/^author:/`

You can write it like this:

```
sed -i '0,/^author:/{/^author:/a goodbye
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/^author:/{a goodbye' -e ':a;n;ba}' file
```

Focus on the first line containing `author:`, then append `goodbye` and loop through all remaining lines.